# TFS - add all test cases from test suite

Tags: testing, tfs

I have a problem regarding copying test cases from one test suite to another. I want to copy all test cases in specific test suite to another one (or copy test suite with all test cases from one test plan to another). I try to do so with query and with no luck for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try MTM, could also use `Tcm.exe` command to copy test suites. It's designed for copying across projects, but it's also available within the same project.

To copy test cases, or test suites across projects, you can use “clone” via the command line (tcm.exe).

Below sample for your reference:

```
Run cmd
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
tcm suites /clone /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC /teamproject:0418Scrum /suiteid:271 /destinationteamproject:TFVC-Scrum /destinationsuiteid:274 /overridefield:"System.IterationPath"="TFVC-Scrum\Sprint 2" /overridefield:"System.AreaPath"=TFVC-Scrum
```

Reference my answer in this thread: [TFS Test Plans Merge from different Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153455/tfs-test-plans-merge-from-different-projects/46167599#46167599)